# USB floppy key

Tags: usb, floppy

Does there exist a USB key that acts like a 1.44MB floppy drive?  I know there are USB floppy drives and USB flash drives, but if I can find a floppy key, I can finally get rid of the floppy disks entirely.  The ideal product would work like those off brand memory cards for the Playstation that had multiple memory pages that could be changed with a button.

I know USB keys can be made bootable, but I work with older servers that support USB floppies but not bootable keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HP sell them, they do exactly what you asked about, bit spendy though - about £40 for 1Gb - HP part number is 442085-B21.

Comment: I thought I'd never find one of these. Thanks! I found that there is a 256MB version with part number 442084-B21 that's 2/3 the price.

Comment: Great news, I didn't know they did a 256Mb version to be honest - I bought the 1GB ones as floppies and as VMWare 3i boot disks so needed the 1GB version. Anyway, glad you're happy :)